# If a player loses his footwear while scoring a goal will it be considered a legal goal?

Tags: rules, football, equipment

Suppose a player loses his footwear accidentally while playing and then scores a goal without wearing his footwear. Will it be considered a legal goal?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There is a law regarding such situation:

See [IFAB Law 4 - The players' equipment](http://www.theifab.com/laws/the-players-equipment/chapters/compulsory-equipment):

> A player whose footwear or shinguard is lost accidentally must replace it as soon as possible and no later than when the ball next goes out of play; if before doing so the player plays the ball and/or scores a goal, the goal is awarded.

Answer (score 10):

> NB: hims056's answer is correct according to the law but I will add the following supporting information.

A lot is said in football about the referee's "interpretation" of the rules in a match.  In the interpretation of this law, we should look closely at the term "immediately".

You will very rarely see a referee award a free kick against a player who passes or shoots with an un-booted foot.  The player is at a disadvantage by being missing a boot so the generally-seen interpretation is that the player has had his shoe removed by accident.

With regards to the immediacy of the event, you're not likely to see a player running around for 15 minutes without a boot so pretty much any time from the loss of the boot up to the next time there is a break in the play could be deemed (interpreted) as immediate.

To sum up the interpretation as simply as possible; if the player has lost a boot and he hasn't had chance to replace it, then he will not have a foul awarded against him.

Earlier this year, [Alessandro Matri scored for Juventus](http://www.dailymail.co.uk/sport/football/article-2276436/Alessandro-Matri-scores-boot-Juventus-Fiorentina--VIDEO.html) wearing no boot on his right foot.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Because it was an accidental, the goal would still be considered legal as there will be no violation.

"If a player loses his footwear accidentally and immediately plays the ball and/or
scores a goal, there is no infringement and the goal is awarded because he lost
his footwear by accident."